# Library for multi-part form data request in iOS

Tags: ios, post, file-upload, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload an image to a server with multipart form data. I was trying it with NSURLConnection and NSMutableURLRequest. But I couldn't get it work. Then I came across ASIHTTPRequest and its support for multipart form requests. But I understand that it is no longer being maintained. Does anyone know of a similar library that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

You can start using AFNetworking. It's an awesome Library :

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: Thanks, I will try and let you know. :)